# Is there a reason why Gmail/Inbox action urls are limited to 256 characters?

Tags: google-schemas

We recently added Gmail/Inbox go-to actions to our emails and we noticed that some of the actions' URL are cut off at exactly 256 characters.
I was wondering if it's a bug on Google's side or if it's documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Types of error messages](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3500741?hl=en), so as not to encounter an invalid or missing website error:

> Enter the complete URL, including the http:// and https://. This field has a **maximum limit of 256 characters**. This URL should be valid, and should not contain any invalid characters (<,>, etc.).

There is actually an existing [quality guidelines](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177) that were created to maintain high quality information on Google. Following these guidelines helps avoid common problems, including changes to your information, or, in some cases, removal of your business information from Google.

You may find the common errors that you may see in your account and the corresponding corrective actions in the given documentations.